# Logstash in EC2 can't send log data to AWS Elasticsearch service

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, amazon-elasticsearch

In EC2 I have configured logstash as belows

```
input {
#       beats{
#       port => 5044
# }


  file {
        type => "adjustlog"
        path => "/etc/logstash/conf.d/sample.log"
        start_position => "beginning"
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }

}

filter {
        if[type] == 'adjustlog'{
                grok {
                    match => {
        "message" => [
           "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp},(%{USERNAME:userId})?,%{USERNAME:setlkey},%{USERNAME:uniqueId},%{NUMBER:providerId},%{USERNAME:itemCode},%{USERNAME:voucherCode},%{USERNAME:samsCode},(%{USERNAME:serviceType})?"
        ]
                }
        }
        }else {
        drop{ }
        }
}


output {
elasticsearch{
               hosts => ["search-*.es.amazonaws.com:80"]
                index => "test"
                }
 stdout {codec => rubydebug}

}
```

but logstash can't make index in AWS elasticsearch and
send log data.
(However, curl and wget commands are working well.
I can make index using curl command)

Error logs are

```
Attempted to send a bulk request to Elasticsearch configured at '["http://search-*.es.amazonaws.com/"]', but an error occurred and it failed! Are you sure you can reach elasticsearch from this machine using the configuration provided? {:error_message=>"search*.es.amazonaws.com:80 failed to respond", :error_class=>"Manticore::ClientProtocolException", :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.6.0-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:37:in `initialize'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281:in `call'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.6.0-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:79:in `call'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.6.0-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:256:in `call_once'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/manticore-0.6.0-java/lib/manticore/response.rb:153:in `code'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.17/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/manticore.rb:84:in `perform_request'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281:in `call'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.17/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:257:in `perform_request'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.17/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/http/manticore.rb:67:in `perform_request'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.17/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:128:in `perform_request'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-api-1.0.17/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/bulk.rb:88:in `bulk'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.7.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:53:in `non_threadsafe_bulk'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.7.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:38:in `bulk'", "org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149:in `synchronize'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.7.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/http_client.rb:38:in `bulk'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.7.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:172:in `safe_bulk'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.7.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:101:in `submit'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.7.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:86:in `retrying_submit'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.7.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:29:in `multi_receive'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1653:in `each_slice'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-2.7.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:28:in `multi_receive'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.3-java/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:130:in `worker_multi_receive'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.3-java/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:114:in `multi_receive'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.3-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:301:in `output_batch'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.3-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:301:in `output_batch'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.3-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:232:in `worker_loop'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.3-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:201:in `start_workers'"], :client_config=>{:hosts=>["http://search*.es.amazonaws.com/"], :ssl=>nil, :transport_options=>{:socket_timeout=>0, :request_timeout=>0, :proxy=>nil, :ssl=>{}}, :transport_class=>Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::HTTP::Manticore, :logger=>nil, :tracer=>nil, :reload_connections=>false, :retry_on_failure=>false, :reload_on_failure=>false, :randomize_hosts=>false, :http=>{:scheme=>"http", :user=>nil, :password=>nil, :port=>80}}, :level=>:error}
```

What is the check point for debug?

Comment: Are you sure about your host name/port configuration? You'll also have to check the security group and port configuration. I've never used aws-elasticsearchservice, but I think that's a good starting point.

Comment: Solved issue. :) That is MTU issue of AWS, I have decrease the MTU value then it's working well.

Comment: Perhaps you could answer your own question so that people having the same problem can find a solution. (cf http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Ok.  Mr Baudsp. Thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

I found this when trying to fix a similar issue. AWS has changed how it implements Elasticsearch node discovery. It will work fine until logstash tries to discover more hosts at which point it breaks. Restarting logstash temporarily but inconsistently fixes the issue. curl and wget work fine too.

```
:message=>"Cannot get new connection from pool.", :class=>"Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Error", :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.15/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:193:in `perform_request'",
```

ElasticSearch would work for a bit but then stop ingesting data.

Old config which failed

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://search-*.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"]
    sniffing => true
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
}
```

Logstash tries to get a list of hosts from Elasticsearch but AWS's implementation has changed the format of the data returned. For more details on the specifics. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=222600
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasitcsearch-ruby-raises-cannot-get-new-connection-from-pool-error/36252/11

The working config.

```
output
 {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["https://search-*.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"]
    manage_template => false
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    document_type => "%{[@metadata][type]}"
  }
}
```

[tomwj](http://tomwj.com)